# Function for link in text

Tags: php

I was using following function to display links  in text that users input . It was working fine but now it has some problems . I cant find where the problem appears.

FUNCTION:

```
function hyperlink($text) { 

$make_link = function($url_index, $elide) { 
    return function($part)use($url_index, $elide) { 

        $url = $part[$url_index]; 

        $text_link = (strlen($url) > $elide) ? substr($url, 0, $elide) . "..." . substr($url,-1) : $url; 

        return $part[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" title=\"Click to visit: $url\" target=\"_blank\">$text_link</a>"; 
    }; 
}; 

$text = preg_replace_callback('#(^| |\n)([a-zA-Z]+://)([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*#', $make_link(0, 19), $text); 
$text = preg_replace_callback("#(^| |\n)(www([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9_/-])*)#", $make_link(2, 15), $text); 
return $text; }
```

Than if i do it like this

```
$analiza2 = $row['analiza']; // Text type in mysql database
echo hyperlink($analiza2);
```

It returns like on picture:

[image]

Any ideas ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do with the second regex, but the first can be fixed fairly easily.

```
[\s\n]*(http[s]?:\/\/[\w.-\/]*[[?]?[\w\-=\/]+]?)
```

This will match any string which starts with `http://` or `https://` and will include everything up to a space or closing punctuation.  The only thing that won't match are periods in the query string.  Most browsers will accept periods in the query string and convert them to underscores, so some people use periods in URLs.  If you run into that you can modify the regex a bit, but it's not very common and it's probably not worth the complexity that it adds.